# Fit image inside flexible Div box without distorting image

Tags: html, css

Trying to fit an image inside a Div box that changes dimensions according to screen size. Still new to this.

I need this image to always keep it's proportion and be cropped by the Div box that may be vertical or horizontal. Preferably I want the Image to be centered on the Div box and with a 5px bleed.

Optionally, is it also possible to set a focus point on the image so that point is what is centered when Div box changes size?

Many thanks!

Here's my current code, where to improve so that Image gets cropped by Div?

```css
body {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  background: #f0e8e6;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

#container {
  max-width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  /* wrong calc? */
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div>

    <img src="https://euclois.xyz/desert-statue.jpg">


  </div>

  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: I love this question! It's been a while since I've seen someone on SO make a (pretty clear) sketch on paper in order to ask a question.

Comment: Thanks, coming from a more creative background (architecture) I tend to always sketch my ideas on paper and get them across like that.  I will continue with the sketches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work best as a [CSS background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#constituent_properties).

- `background-size: cover` will expand/shrink the image to cover the entire background without distorting the aspect ratio.
- The `5px` "bleed" is achieved with a combination of `padding: 5px`, `background-clip: content-box`, and `background-origin: border-box`.
- The "focal point" can be adjusted with [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) or [`background-position-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position-x) and [`background-position-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position-y).

```css
body {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: #f0e8e6;
  background-image: url("https://euclois.xyz/desert-statue.jpg");
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: 60%;
  background-position-y: 35%;
  background-size: cover;
}

#container {
  max-width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped, very useful for the future. simple code easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

I think using `object-fit: cover` on the img tag will do instead of `contain`. Is this what you wanted to do: https://codesandbox.io/s/object-fit-issue-0n63py

Comment: That's it man, thanks. Didn't come across `cover` in my searches. Do you perhaps now how to choose a focus point on that image? Let's say I want to always center the image on the figure's head.

Answer (score 0):

use `object-fit: cover;` for the img class, you have used contain.
See here all possible values for `object-fit` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 0):

add `object-fit: cover` on the image and also, instead of -5 width on the image, try padding on the wrapping div,

```
div {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  background: #f0e8e6;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}
```